# Samsung galaxy tab2 P3100 "android.process.media" stopped issue?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I have updated Samsung galaxy tab2 P3100 to jelly bean since then I am getting popup error as "unfortunately the process android.process.media has stopped". Is there any fix available for this?

Comment: Could be the media scanner.... check for any corrupt media files on your /sdcard/. This is just a guess

Comment: How did you update? Did you flash a Custom ROM?

Comment: I have used Samsung official update not custom ROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hay it's a simple problem to encounter, go to settings reset the system don't forget to backup your important data before doing so.